# Is impedance triangle considered as phasor diagram

Tags: impedance

Voltage triangle of series RL circuit considered as phasor diagram, since there is a phase difference between voltage and current in Voltage triangle.

But there is no phase difference concept in impedance triangle, still is it considered as phasor diagram ?

Comment: In order to draw a triangle, you need some lines and some angles. Those angles are phase differences between the elements (lines) of your circuit

Comment: A phasor is a rotating vector representing a sinusoidal signal that is frozen at a particular value of time. So, strictly, the vectors in an impedance triangle are not phasors.